# React Bootstrap Overwrite Color of Form on Hover/Click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to overwrite the color of a `React-Bootstrap` `Form` component. I'd like the background color to be of hex #44494f instead of the default blue in this image:

[image]

Now here's my code- I've tried editing the `search-bar` class via `background-color`, `border-color`, or `color` but none of them seem to work:

```
export const Markets = () => {

  return (
      <Form className="search-bar">
        <Form.Control
          placeholder="Search Markets"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: you can try color: #44494f !important;

Comment: @Bharat this doesn't work too unfortunately..

Comment: try to see which style is overriding the style you are giving using inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this,

```
.search-bar {
background-color: #44494f !important;
}
```

or

```
<Form className="search-bar" style="background-color: #44494f">
```

Comment: Check whether it is inside a shadow root, if so you can use :host selector